# Refreshing the contents of a UITableView freezes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, uirefreshcontrol

I have a problem when refreshing my data in my UITableview. Currently have a UIRefreshControl that when triggered (by pulling down), executes the following:

```
- (void)refreshByScrolling:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl {
    [self refreshPriceInformation];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

At this point the UI freezes (expect for the spinning refreshControl, until the  [self refreshPriceInformation] method is completed.

Is there anyway to make it the UI won't freeze when I'm refreshing the data? For example, on the twitter and Instagram apps you can pull down to refresh and right after start scrolling down on the table.

The code for the  [self refreshPriceInformation] is below

```
-(void)refreshPriceInformation
{

isRefreshing = true;

//Creating Queues for Concurrent refreshes
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);


dispatch_apply([watchedSkinList count], queue, ^(size_t i) {

        SkinToWatch *watchedSkin =[watchedSkinList objectAtIndex:i];
        [watchedSkin refreshPriceInformation];

});

 dispatch_async(queue, ^{
     NSLog(@"Saving Data to Phone");

     // resaving data to phone
     NSData *newdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:watchedSkinList];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newdata forKey:@"watchSkinsArray"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize ];


    isRefreshing = false;
     [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

     //Updating Refresh Label
     [self updateDateAndSaveDurning:false];

 });



}
```

Thanks!

EDIT******
As HackerInHeels has stated below, wrapping dispatch_apply with DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND has stopped the UI from freezing!

Follow up questions:
1)how do I make sure that this is block of code is executed last?

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         NSLog(@"Saving Data to Phone");

//rest of code...
});
```

Before implementing the solution, it was the last block to execute. After the solution, that's no longer the case. Do I put in it another queue? Make it sync rather than aysnc?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this for me..

Wrap SkinToWatch code within dispatch_async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    dispatch_apply([watchedSkinList count], queue, ^(size_t i) {

    SkinToWatch *watchedSkin =[watchedSkinList objectAtIndex:i];
    [watchedSkin refreshPriceInformation];

    });
});
```

Comment: That seemed to have done it! Thank you. Also, would you happen to know where to put code if I wanted to update the UI of individual cells durning the update? So I could activate an activity indicator?

Comment: great! the cell data is updated in cellForRowAtIndexPath - when your underlying data model changes, call reloadData and that should trigger tableview delegate functions which should be looking at the updated data model.. so you shouldnt really need to do any thing else other than reloadData. if that doesnt answer your question, pls update the question above or create a new one, and i will take a look

Comment: why dont you put that piece of code after [watchedSkin refreshPriceInformation]; in the same block of code

Comment: I don't think that piece of code would work after [watchedSkin refreshPriceInformation]. This is because I have to wait for all price information for each skin to be refreshed before saving to the phone. I hope this made sense

Comment: is it beign refreshed in refreshPriceInformation? If yes, then why dont you pass in a "save to disk" block of code as a param to refreshPriceInformation function. That function will take the block of code and execute if the update was success else it can ignore it

Comment: Nevermind I just mistook what you said. I just moved that block inside the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND and put it below the  dispatch_apply and its working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can anyone give the swift solution for this? Am stuck with this for many hours! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        });
```

instead of

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: The UI still freezes when trying this. Thanks though